# Add module as reference in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to implement following csc command based compilation with the Roslyn Microsoft.Codeanalysis library

```
csc /target:library /out:UserControlBase.dll UserControlBase.cs /addmodule:"c:\artifacts\MyLib.netmodule"
```

Following is the implementation of the same with Roslyn

```
var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
//Add Module
compilation.AddReferences(ModuleMetadata.CreateFromFile(@"c:\artifacts\MyLib.netmodule").GetReference());
compilationStatus = compilation.Emit(outputFolderPath + @"\Test1.dll", outputFolderPath + @"\Test1.pdb");
if (!compilationStatus.Success)
{
    foreach (var item in compilationStatus.Diagnostics)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Issue:
.Netmodule is not getting added to the project and compilation failed due to references not resolved from netmodule.

Does anyone know the correct way to add this?

I'm using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis 1.0.0

Comment: "I'm using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis 1.0.0" That's ancient, why don't you use a more recent version? Though it probably won't solve your issue.

Comment: @svick I'm using above in VS extension, older versions of VS doesn't support the leatest Roslyn, Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678861/whats-the-latest-version-of-roslyn-my-analyzer-can-target-if-i-support-vs2015/45680699#45680699

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but the answer could be useful to someone else.

Everything in Roslyn is immutable. So, calling compilation.AddReference doesn't add the reference to the compilation object you have, but instead creates a new compilation object based on the original, with the additional references.

so, for this to work you need to call Emit in the object returned by the AddReference call. You could just replace the compilation variable:

```
compilation = compilation.AddReferences(ModuleMetadata.CreateFromFile(@"c:\artifacts\MyLib.netmodule").GetReference());
```

or use a new variable and call Emit from that:

```
var compWithRefs = compilation.AddReferences(ModuleMetadata.CreateFromFile(@"c:\artifacts\MyLib.netmodule").GetReference());
compilationStatus = compWithRefs.Emit(outputFolderPath + @"\Test1.dll", outputFolderPath + @"\Test1.pdb");
```